# How to use git show with pretty or format that come up with just commit message brief?

Tags: git, shell, github

The output should look like git log, no any file and code changes just commit message brief, as below:

```
commit <sha1>
Author: <author>
Commit: <committer>
<title line>
<full commit message>
```

I have got some tips that git show with pretty or format set to 'full', but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 11):

**`git show --format="YOUR_FORMAT" -s`**

`-s` suppresses the diffs from showing.

`YOUR_FORMAT` is documented at:

```
man git-log
```

section `PRETTY FORMATS`

For example, to get just commit SHAs and author email for a few SHAs:

```
git show --format="%H %ae" -s 62f6870e4e0b384c4bd2d514116247e81b241251 96ee0246ce52012644dd18cf360e64c49016fb7f
```

gives output for format:

```
62f6870e4e0b384c4bd2d514116247e81b241251 author@mail.com
96ee0246ce52012644dd18cf360e64c49016fb7f author@mail.com
```

To add newlines and more fields to the format, you could do:

```
git show --format=$'%H\n%ae\n%an\n' -s 62f6870e4e0b384c4bd2d514116247e81b241251 96ee0246ce52012644dd18cf360e64c49016fb7f
```

Which gives output for form:

```
62f6870e4e0b384c4bd2d514116247e81b241251
author@mail.com
Ciro Santilli

96ee0246ce52012644dd18cf360e64c49016fb7f
author@mail.com
Ciro Santilli
```

Answer (score 5):

Im using this script (as alias):

https://github.com/vheon/home/blob/master/.githelpers

git alias:

```
l = "!bash -c 'source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log'"
```

the output is this:

[image]

---

You will have to use your own `git log --pretty=format` options.

In the `--pretty` you can set colors and choose any content you would like to display

---

> ***`format:<string>`***
>
> The format: format allows you to specify which information you want to show. It works a little bit like printf format, with the notable exception that you get a newline with %n instead of \n.
>
> E.g, format:`The author of %h was %an, %ar%nThe title was >>%s<<%n` would show something like this:

```
The author of fe6e0ee was Junio C Hamano, 23 hours ago
The title was >>t4119: test autocomputing -p<n> for traditional diff input.<<
```

> ***`The placeholders are`***:
>
> `%C(…):` color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option; adding auto, at the beginning will emit color only when colors are enabled for log output (by color.diff, color.ui, or --color, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal). auto alone (i.e. %C(auto)) will turn on auto coloring on the next placeholders until the color is switched again.
>
> `%C(…):` color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option; adding auto, at the beginning will emit color only when colors are enabled for log output (by color.diff, color.ui, or --color, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal). auto alone (i.e. %C(auto)) will turn on auto coloring on the next placeholders until the color is switched again.
>
> `%Cblue:` switch color to blue
>   `%Cgreen:` switch color to green
>   `%Cred:` switch color to red
>   `%Creset:` reset color
>   `%D:` ref names without the " (", ")" wrapping.
>   `%G?:` show "G" for a Good signature, "B" for a Bad signature, "U" for a good, untrusted signature and "N" for no signature
>   `%GG:` raw verification message from GPG for a signed commit
>   `%GK:` show the key used to sign a signed commit
>   `%GS:` show the name of the signer for a signed commit
>   `%H:` commit hash
>   `%N:` commit notes
>   `%P:` parent hashes
>   `%T:` tree hash
>   `%aD:` author date, RFC2822 style
>   `%aE:` author email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%aI:` author date, strict ISO 8601 format
>   `%aN:` author name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%ad:` author date (format respects --date= option)
>   `%ae:` author email
>   `%ai:` author date, ISO 8601-like format
>   `%an:` author name
>   `%ar:` author date, relative
>   `%at:` author date, UNIX timestamp
>   `%b:` body
>   `%cD:` committer date, RFC2822 style
>   `%cE:` committer email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%cI:` committer date, strict ISO 8601 format
>   `%cN:` committer name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%cd:` committer date (format respects --date= option)
>   `%ce:` committer email
>   `%ci:` committer date, ISO 8601-like format
>   `%cn:` committer name
>   `%cr:` committer date, relative
>   `%ct:` committer date, UNIX timestamp
>   `%d:` ref names, like the --decorate option of git-log(1)
>   `%e:` encoding
>   `%f:` sanitized subject line, suitable for a filename
>   `%gD:` reflog selector, e.g., refs/stash@{1}
>   `%gE:` reflog identity email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%gN:` reflog identity name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%gd:` shortened reflog selector, e.g., stash@{1}
>   `%ge:` reflog identity email
>   `%gn:` reflog identity name
>   `%gs:` reflog subject
>   `%h:` abbreviated commit hash
>   `%m:` left, right or boundary mark
>   `%n:` newline
>   `%p:` abbreviated parent hashes
>   `%s:` subject
>   `%t:` abbreviated tree hash
>   `%w([<w>[,<i1>[,<i2>]]]):` switch line wrapping, like the -w option of git-shortlog(1).
>   `%x00:` print a byte from a hex code

Answer (score 4):

To provide an answer that is not as complicated as a separate shell script, but still demonstrates the power of option `--pretty`, I will describe my currently preferred alias for `git log`:

```
[alias]
   lg = log --decorate --graph --pretty=tformat:'%C(dim white)%m%C(dim green)%h %C(dim cyan)%cd %C(yellow)%<(12,trunc)%aN %C(reset)%s%C(auto)%w(0,0,9)%+d%C(reset)' --decorate --graph
```

### Used features in `--pretty`

- `%C(<color name>)` to set text color, `%Creset` to revert (see `git help config` for possible values)
- `%<(<width>,..)` to truncate the commit author name `%aN` to a maximum width for a column-based layout
- `%w(0,0,9)` to have the second line be indented by 9 spaces (roughly the width of an abbreviated commit ID in many repos)
- Prefix `+` in the decoration placeholder `%d` (--> `%+d`) to place branch/tag decorations in a second line, while keeping linear commits tightly spaced
- `%m` boundary mark to discern "left" and "right" commits (rarely used)

### Preview

[image: git lg preview]

I have set the date format in .gitconfig as well:

```
[log]
     date = format:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M
```

Comment: Thanks for `-s`, I missed that one in the doc: I wasn't expecting any output except from the provided format.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
git log --oneline
```

To see only title and beginning of the hash.

For further information check out `git help log`.

Comment: I know this, but what I want is that git show  come up with same output of a commit

Comment: Just use `git log -1`.